# React Native ./gradlew clean ошибка

Tags: react-native

[image]

Команда  ./gradlew clean  выдает вот такую ошибку

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Попробуйте `gradlew clean` вместо `./gradlew clean`

Comment: спасибо помогло